# How to change image link using PHP?

Tags: php, database, url, hyperlink

I have been working on PHP gallery and creating 'pretty URLs'. But before going with the .htaccess route, I would like to see if I can clean up my link using PHP. I am sorry if this sounds so stupid but wanted to see if I can change my link from

`rajeevthomas.com/viewgallery.php?cname=Colorado-Fall&pcaption=Early-Colors` to

`rajeevthomas.com/viewgallery.php/Colorado-Fall/Early-Colors` using just PHP?

Right now this bit of code creates the link.

```
$result_final .= "<div class=limage><table><tr><td><table class=image><tr>\n\t<td><a href=/viewgallery.php?cname=$cname&pcaption=".$caption_array[$next]."><img src='".$images_dir."/".$photo_filename."' border='0' alt='".$photo_keywords."' /></a>
```

Or is this impossible since the link is being created by data pulled from the database?

Comment: What is stopping you from coding `<a href=/viewgallery.php/$cname/$caption_array[$next]>` if you are going to create `pretty URLs` ?

Comment: You need a routing system, you can't just replace query strings with url segments.

Comment: @ We are the World- 'routing system' does that mean .htaccess or can that be done in PHP? Just like curious_coder mentioned above?

Comment: Which PHP framework you are using. If you are using any MVC Framework like Codeigniter, laravel etc. THey have their routing system. That pretty match with your requirement.

Comment: Murtaza... I am not using any framework now ( I think? ) plus I am a newbie so I really don't know much so I think I am not using a framework.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but you should modify both .htaccess file and index.php file.

Modify .htaccess file is for the server to understand the routing and index.php file is for application side.

Sample .htaccess file as follows,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Just go through [this](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/74170-clean-urls-with-php/) tutorial. Then you can get an idea how to do that.

Comment: Janith...Thank you for your answer and for giving me something to go on with.